# Problem with creating a list of string after a transform in Haskell

Tags: haskell

If I get a list of string like ["Dog", "red", "caR", "HELLO"] and I want to convert the lower case into upper case and vice versa using fold instruction, how can I return a list of string?

The return should be like ["dOG", "RED", "CAr", "hello"]

I have this code

```
convertWords :: [String] -> String
convertWords words= foldl(\ r it ->r++foldl(\ rr iitt ->if isUpper iitt then rr++[toLower iitt] else rr++[toUpper iitt]) [] it) [] words
```

The problem is that it returns a good conversion, but in one list like:

"dOGREDCArhello"

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I get a list of string like ["Dog", "red", "caR", "HELLO"] and I want to convert the lower case into upper case and vice versa using fold instruction, how can I return a list of string?

If for given list of strings you want to have a list of strings as well, the type of such a function will be `convertWords :: [String] -> [String]`.

For every `String` inside a list you need to apply another function that will swap the case `convertWord :: String -> String`. Thus, `convertWords = map convertWord`.

Given that switching the case is applicable only for `Char`, and `String = [Char]`, we also need to have `convertChar :: Char -> Char` function, so `convertWord = map convertChar`.

Definition for `convertChar` might look like that:

```
convertChar :: Char -> Char
convertChar c | isUpper c = toLower c
              | otherwise = toUpper c
```

And finally,

```
convertWord :: String -> String
convertWord = map convertChar

convertWords :: [String] -> [String]
convertWords = map convertWord
```

We have the correct result:

```
>> convertWords ["Dog", "red", "caR", "HELLO"]
["dOG","RED","CAr","hello"]
it :: [String]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `if then else` for the binary condition of `being upper or not being upper` together with a `map` could look like this:

```
converter i = map (map(\x -> if isUpper x then toLower x else toUpper x)) i
```

If you would like to use foldl we need to look at the signature for foldl :

`foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`

So we could create a function to take a list of String, a String and return a manipulated version of that String inside the list.

`folder :: [String] -> String -> [String]`

To stay with the `if then else` to easier see the difference would look something like this:

```
folder :: [String] -> String -> [String]
folder xs  "" = []
folder xs s   = xs ++ [sb s]

 where sb ""     = ""
       sb (c:cc) = if isUpper c then toLower c : sb cc else toUpper c : sb cc
```

This could of course and preferable be changed to match on guards instead, i leave that up you to.

With this function `folder` we could now use `foldl` because the signatures match. Giving `foldl` our `folder` and an empty list and the input list as arguments will solve the problem:

`converter' xs = foldl folder [] xs`